# How to send AWS DynamoDB Stream from Lambda to API Gateway to Front end?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, server-sent-events

I have a dynamodb stream triggering a lambda function. The lambda function is receiving information successfully returning it like so:

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: "data: " + JSON.stringify({ message: stream }) + "\n\n",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
}
```

As of now everything works up until this point.

On the front end I am using Javascript EventSource

```
    const source = new EventSource(api)
    source.onmessage = event => {
      resolve(event.data)
    }
    source.onerror = error => {
      reject(error)
    }
```

It listens for the stream from an API Gateway rest api using lambda proxy integration with the above described lambda function. I have set the api's method response model to `text/event-stream` .

When I run the app, on the front end, all i receive is an empty Javascript object `{}`.

How do I get that data which is in the lambda function to my EventSource function on the front end?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK its not possible to use API Gateway as an event source for EventSource. The next best thing would be to use [API Gateway Web Sockets API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html)